# AngularJS adding content to the routing for a back button

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-routing

```
.when('/football', {
    templateUrl : 'assets/pages/football/home.html',
    controller  : 'footballController'
})
.when('/football/teams', {
    templateUrl : 'assets/pages/football/teams.html',
    controller  : 'footballController'
})
```

I have the above to route my application, but I'm curious if there is a way to set a variable here?

I have a navbar in the application that has a back button, I'd like to set a string so that if someone is on `/football/teams` and clicks back, it will take them to `/football` instead of using `history` `.back()`

If possible it would be easier to be able to do this from the routing section

Answer (score 0):

you could try to use resolve param of when method:

```
.when('/football', {
    templateUrl : 'assets/pages/football/home.html',
    controller  : 'footballController'
    resolve: {
            setVar: function ($route, dataService) {
                return dataService.set($route.current.params.id);
            }
        }
})
```

dataService - it's your own service to share the state of variables.

Here you could find an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/derkoe/Wk7WD/presentation/